# html select tag problem

Tags: html, html-select

`enter code here`i am using the folllowing code . I wnat that the only single option is selected. but right now its showing some other options as selected by defaul when the page loads.
How can i make one particular of my choice o selected?

```
<select name="ms">                                                                                       <option value="-1" selected="false"  >any</option>
                <option value="0" selected="true" >only single</option>
                <option value="1" selected="false" >only married</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 2):

The selected attribute's presence alone is enough to make the option selected.  You will need to remove the `selected="false"` text from the second option to make this work.  selected and disabled are similar in this respect.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers generally only check if the selected attribute exists. Therefore you should change your code to:

```
<select name="ms">                                                                                    
        <option value="-1">any</option>
        <option value="0" selected="selected">only single</option>
        <option value="1">only married</option>
</select>
```

EDIT: Looks like you edited your example so I'll edit mine.

Answer (score 1):

HTML4 + HTML5 : use attribute minimization; therefore use the attribute 'selected' for the selected option (no attribute for the others)

```
<select name="ms">                                                                                       <option value="-1" selected="false"  >any</option>
            <option value="0" selected>only single</option>
            <option value="1">only married</option>
</select>
```

XHTML :  attribute minimization is forbidden, meaning you need to assign a value to the attribute, i.e. selected="selected" (which is the only value it takes)

```
<select name="ms">                                                                                       <option value="-1" selected="false"  >any</option>
            <option value="0" selected="selected">only single</option>
            <option value="1">only married</option>
</select>
```

Check the DOCTYPE of your html page/file to see if you use XHTML or HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Don't supply the "selected" attribute at all, if the option isn't selected.  This will work better:

```
<select name="ms">
   <option value="-1" >any</option>
   <option value="0" selected >only single</option>
   <option value="1" >only married</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You should use selected="selected" though, as that is actually more correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value="0" selected="selected" >only single</option>
            <option value="1" >only married</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="ms">
    <option value="-1" selected="false"  >any</option>
    <option value="0" selected="true" >only single</option>
    <option value="1">only married</option>
</select>
```